# Taking fire from Yahrtzeit candle to light Yom Tov candles

Tags: halacha, yom-tov, candle-lighting, yahrtzeit, fire-burning

On the second night of Yom Tov, can one take fire from a yartzeit candle to light your Yom Tov candles?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Kate! Can you include the issue that one would want to avoid in this situation? I.e. why would you expect this to be a problem?

Comment: My family is not frum and start the Seder early because they have toddlers. They start around 5-5:30. Someone told me I could do Maggid with them but couldn’t light, have kiddish or matzah before a certain time. However, I was told I could light early but wasn’t told how early. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 4):

The Mishnah Berurah 154:56 writes that one should not use a ner from the bais kenesses to light a tobacco pipe, but one may use a yartzeit candle to do so. The Piskei Teshuvos 514 brings this source as well that one can use a yartzeit candle for their own personal needs when necessary.

So according to these opinions it would be permissible to take fire from ones yartzeit candle to light yom tov candles.

Text of MB:

> לצורך גדול:    ולענין להדליק הפיפ"א של טאבא"ק מנר של ביהכ"נ עיין בש"ת
>   שפוסק לאיסור מנר של תפלה ואך מנר של יא"צ שדולק כל המעל"ע יש להתיר. כתב
>   ס"ח סימן תתי"ג לא יקח נר לבקש מעותיו אבל אם ירא פן נחבאו גנבים בביהכ"נ
>   יקח נר ויחפש [א"ר] ולענ"ד אחר שכתב רמ"א דלצורך גדול אמרינן לב ב"ד מתנה
>   מסתברא דשרי נמי ליקח נר לחפש מעותיו שנפלו ממנו:‏